# blur TextInput when closing keyboard using android back button

Tags: react-native, reactjs

I would like to execute `this.refs.textInput.blur();` when a user press the hardware back button in android, which closes the keyboard. Tried using the `hardwareBackPress` listener but it only works when keyboard is closed.

Is there any way to listen to this event? Thanks for helping!

Comment: may try `dismissKeyboard` ? Like `var dismissKeyboard = require('dismissKeyboard');` and then call it like `dismissKeyboard()`

Comment: @Cherniv i added that to the listener together with the `blur()` and i doesn't seems to be working